# Accessing a subscribers data at a different rate

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, thanks for any and all responses, but simply:

I am running a control loop that generates and publishes new velocities at 100hz, every-time it calculates a new velocity it needs the current motor shaft position data. However, this position data is subscribed To and arriving at a much higher rate than the control is running.

How can I/best method for accessing the current data from this subscribed to topic at the moment I need it in the control loop?

An example:

```
ros::Subscriber pointSub;
ros::Subscriber posSub;

float phi = 0.0;     /// a global variable that gets updated 


void controlLoop(const geometry_msgs::Point & currentPoint) {
  //RUNS ONCE!!! triggered by arriving x,y,z point data

  ros::Rate rate(100)
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++)
  {

      //HERE I WANT THE UPDATED, most recent, PHI VALUE

      ros::spinOnce();
      rate.sleep();
  }
  
} //END OF control loop

void fastPositionCb(const std_msgs::Float64 currPos) {
  //Gets data published faster than 100hz .... say 1kHz

  phi = CurrPos.data;

}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "example");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  pointSub = nh.subscribe("testPoint", 1, controlLoop);  // happens once
  posSub = nh.subscribe("phiPos", 1, fastPositionCb);   // happens very fast

  // Spin
  ros::spin();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342889/accessing-a-subscribers-data-at-a-different-rate/) by [PatFGarrett](https://answers.ros.org/users/34824/patfgarrett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2020-01-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-01-30**:
I'm not sure to fully understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to call the `controlLoop` callback faster than the `fastPositionCb` or only with the latest data received ?

Anyway I would change your code to have your callbacks only receiving the data and assigning it to some global variables (or better using classes) because looping in a callback is really not adivised, you should only do simple operations inside callbacks to ensure you receive all the messages. So the main would have a loop like this :

```
ros::Rate rate(YOUR_DESIRED_RATE)
while (ros::ok())
{
    //Do what you need to with the data you received
    ros::spinOnce();
    rate.sleep();
}
```

Correct me if I misunderstood your issue I'll correct my suggestion accordingly.

**Comment by [PatFGarrett](https://answers.ros.org/users/34824/patfgarrett/) on 2020-01-30**:
Delb,
Thanks for the response, and I apologize for not being very clear. But you are basically right... I want To harness the data coming in from a very fast topic and use it at a a rate of 100Hz. I adjusted my sample code To hopefully show this better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on your edit I would suggest to look into [message_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters), specifically the [Cache](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Cache) class.

From the wiki page:

> Stores a time history of messages.

> Given a stream of messages, the most recent N messages are cached in a ring buffer, from which time intervals of the cache can then be retrieved by the client. The timestamp of a message is determined from its header field.

So whenever you receive a message on the "slow" stream, look into your `Cache` and retrieve the message from the fast stream that corresponds to the same `header.stamp`.

If you'd like to automate this process you could even use a policy-based synchronizer, probably the [ApproximateTime Policy](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#ApproximateTime_Policy). This will allow you to register a callback which will only be called when there are matching messages in both datastreams.

You might have to play with the buffer and/or slack time, depending on how disparate the two message rates are.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PatFGarrett](https://answers.ros.org/users/34824/patfgarrett/) on 2020-01-30**:
Gvdhoorn,

Hello and thank you for response. If i understand your answer and what I read about message_filters is that they create a que of messages as they arrive. So I would fill that up with my "fast topic" and then as my slow function needs it i just pick off the top? The only issues I see is does this make them run in parallel? Will i be able To access the fast channels que at any given time... I guess ya that makes sense, if there isnt a brand new message it will get the ques top/last item.

Ultimately in my "slow loop" i want  To call something that, although hypothetically, would look like this:

data = some_subscriber.getTopicDataNow();